# Matlab GUI Pushbutton update graph each time pressed

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure

I've developed a GUI to keep track of a betting fund. It tells you how much to bet relative to your fund size. The basics of it are that it has 2 push buttons, either win or lose. Every time either is pressed it updates the fund size and tells you what to bet (10%) where the win / loss rate is double or nothing.

An example is in the picture below. If the initial fund is £1000, and we let a win be = 1, and a loss = 0

[image]

When the pushbutton is pressed it only shows the new fund size and bet size. Im looking for a way to plot the results such that it will plot all the newFundSize (y-axis) against count (x-axis) so it will show you how your fund size has changed over time(number of bets).

It currently changes the x-axis to the correct length, 
    x1 = linspace(1:currentCount). 
For the Y value I can only recall the previous fund size and the new fund size.

Is it possible to somehow plot all the new fund size data? Or store all the previous fund size values?

Also it there a way to store the order and number of times the win or lose pushbutton is pressed?

for example, win, win, lose, win , lose, win would be stored as [1 1 0 1 0 1]?

Thanks.

Comment: can you reformat that 2nd paragraph? I don't understand the example. thanks!

Comment: Yes I have done. Hope that makes it easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to store all of this information within MATLAB. There are several ways to do this, but the best is usually to store the data within the figure itself. You can do this using [guidata](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html), [setappdata and getappdata](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html), or the `UserData` property of the figure.

Below I have an example using the `setappdata` approach where I store the information in a data structure that is an array of structures that has the following form

```
data =

      win: true    % Logical indicating whether it was a winning bet
     fund: 1000    % Amount of money in the fund
    count: 0       % The number of bets placed so far (optional)
```

Each time the user places a bet, I append another structure of the above format to the data structure.

Here is the full example.

```
function data = bet(initialFund, betPercentage)
    if ~exist('initialBet', 'var')
        initialFund = 1000;
    end

    if ~exist('betPercentage', 'var')
        betPercentage = 10;
    end

    % The data structure that we will use to keep track of the bets
    data = struct('win', NaN, 'fund', initialFund, 'count', 0);

    % Now create the figure and the plot that you want
    fig = figure();

    hax = axes(...
        'Parent', fig, ...
        'Units', 'normalized', ...
        'Position', [0.15 0.35 0.7 0.6]);

    % Plot to display current fund data
    plt = plot(NaN, NaN, 'Parent', hax);

    xlabel(hax, 'Bet', 'FontWeight', 'bold', 'FontSize', 18)
    ylabel(hax, 'Fund ($)', 'FontWeight', 'bold', 'FontSize', 18)

    set(hax, 'FontWeight', 'bold')

    % Create a button to place a winning and losing bet
    uicontrol(fig, ...
        'String', 'Place Winning Bet', ...
        'Units', 'normalized', ...
        'Position', [0.01 0.01 0.45 0.2], ...
        'Callback', @(s,e)place_bet(true, betPercentage/100));

    uicontrol(fig, ...
        'String', 'Place Losing Bet', ...
        'Units', 'normalized', ...
        'Position', [0.5 0.01 0.45 0.2], ...
        'Callback', @(s,e)place_bet(false, betPercentage/100));

    % Store the data within the handle
    setappdata(fig, 'BetData', data)

    % Plot the initial bet data
    refreshPlot(data);

    function place_bet(win_lose, percentage)
        % Determine whether we win or lose
        data = getappdata(fig, 'BetData');

        % Now add the new data
        lastbet = data(end);

        % Compute the new fund based on the bet amount
        newfund = (1 - ((-1)^win_lose) * percentage) * lastbet.fund;

        newdata = struct(...
            'win', win_lose, ...
            'fund', newfund, ...
            'count', lastbet.count + 1);

        data = cat(1, data, newdata);

        % Store the updated data
        setappdata(fig, 'BetData', data)

        % Now update the plot
        refreshPlot(data);
    end

    function refreshPlot(data)
        set(plt, 'XData', [data.count], 'YData', [data.fund])
        set(hax, 'XLim', [data(1).count, max(data(end).count, 10)])
    end
end
```